# How to read meta-data from video using vlc-qt libvlc in Qt

Tags: qt, libvlc, vlc-qt

I am developing a media player in Qt and using `libvlc` as my base to built the player. Now I want to read the various information about the video like it's resolution, codec, duration etc.

I have tried to extract the metadata using '''libvlc''' but they require the video to be played to read the metadata.

I want to read metadata without playing the video file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `mediainfo` to read the metadata as `mediainfo` don't require you to play the video to extract the information from the video.